# How do I add component to different divs according to ngFor's index value in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I wrote such a code to explain my problem.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products | async; index as i">
  <app-product-card [product]="product"></app-product-card>
</ng-container>

<div class="row">

  <!--Grid column-->
  <div id="gridColumn1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
    <!-- if (i%3 == 0) -->
  </div>
  <!--Grid column-->

  <!--Grid column-->
  <div id="gridColumn2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <!-- if (i%3 == 1) -->
  </div>
  <!--Grid column-->

  <!--Grid column-->
  <div id="gridColumn3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <!-- if (i%3 == 2) -->
  </div>
  <!--Grid column-->

</div>
<!--Grid row-->
```

With `ngFor` I am creating a card for each product.

What I want to do; If `i%3 == 0` add the product-card to `gridColum1`, if it is 1 add it to `gridColum2`, if it is 2 add it to `gridColum3`. How can I do that?

I can group the product array by index and return it as a two-dimensional array, but I don't like this.
It can be done using javascript but here I want to take advantage of the power of angular.
But I'm new to angular, so I couldn't find a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not exactly what I want. In your example, separate gridColumn are created for each product. I want to have 3 fixed gridColumns and add card into these gridColumns according to their index values. For example, if I have 6 products, twice cards must be added to each of the 3 gridColumns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows;

First, I wrote a pipe doing the grouping by index value.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'groupByMod'
})
export class GroupByModPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform<T>(value: Array<T>, mod: number): Array<Array<T>> {

    if (mod < 2) {
      return new Array<Array<T>>(value);
    }

    const matrix = new Array<Array<T>>();
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (i < mod) {
        matrix[i] = new Array<T>();
      }
      matrix[i % mod].push(value[i]);
    }
    return matrix;
  }
}
```

Then I changed the html code as follows.

```
<div class="row">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let productArray of products | async | groupByMod:3; index as i;" [ngSwitch]="i">

    <!--Grid column 1-->
    <div *ngSwitchCase="0" id="gridColumn1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4">
      <app-product-card *ngFor="let product of productArray" [product]="product"></app-product-card>
    </div>

    <!--Grid column 2-->
    <div *ngSwitchCase="1" id="gridColumn2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <app-product-card *ngFor="let product of productArray" [product]="product"></app-product-card>
    </div>

    <!--Grid column 3-->
    <div *ngSwitchCase="2" id="gridColumn3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
      <app-product-card *ngFor="let product of productArray" [product]="product"></app-product-card>
    </div>

  </ng-container>


</div>
<!--Grid row-->
```

It's doing my job for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have a solution for you. You can do that using `ngIf`. Here is my code and stackblitz link Below => [Demo Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-inside-ngfor-dtb5j1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-product-card%2Fapp-product-card.component.html)
.
 **Child HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngIf='index%3==0'  id="gridColumn1" class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 mb-4" style="background:red">gridColumn1
  </div>
  <div *ngIf='index%3==1' id="gridColumn2" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4" style="background:blue">gridColumn2
  </div>
  <div *ngIf='index%3==2' id="gridColumn3" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4"  style="background:green" >gridColumn3
  </div>
</div>
```

**Child TS:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-card',
  templateUrl: './app-product-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-product-card.component.css']
})
export class AppProductCardComponent  {
  @Input() index:number;
  @Input() product:any;
}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products; index as i">
  <app-product-card [product]="product" [index]="i"></app-product-card>
</ng-container>
```

**Parent TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 products=[];
 constructor(){
   for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
       let temp=new Product();
       temp.pCode="PC-"+i.toString();
       temp.pName="PN-"+i.toString();
       this.products.push(temp);
    }
 }
}
export class Product{
  pName:string;
  pCode:string
}
```

**Note:** I have addded `style=background` to check which div is showing.